# Using 'acquiesced' in a sentence, is 'acquiesced into' valid?

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality

I have a sentence that is framed as

> I know I did, especially when I’d be acquiesced into something like listening to a boring lecture or playing soccer.

I've been told that this is incorrect, or 'not kosher'. How can I rewrite this to be more appropriate without changing the meaning?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84143/discussion-on-question-by-bholagabbar-using-acquiesced-in-a-sentence-is-acqu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you should not do is using *to acquiesce in sth.* in passive voice. Use active voice:

> Every student has asked himself this fundamental question at some key points in time, “What is my purpose ? What am I really supposed to be doing ?”. I know I did, especially **when I acquiesced in** something like listening to a boring lecture, or playing soccer.

Or if you want to put more emphasise on being forced to do something (and you respectfully and out of courtesy decided to accept the situation although you actually found it unpleasant or inappopriate):

> Every student has asked himself this fundamental question at some key points in time, “What is my purpose ? What am I really supposed to be doing ?”. I know I did, especially **when I was forced to acquiesce in** something like listening to a boring lecture, or playing soccer.

This is grammatically correct. However, it has a problem with semantics: *to acquiesc* already carries an element of meaning saying "there is some force in play that makes me do things I do not actually want to do". Adding *to be forced* would be at least to some extent redundant. You can avoid this by simply saying:

> Every student has asked himself this fundamental question at some key points in time, “What is my purpose ? What am I really supposed to be doing ?”. I know I did, especially **when I was forced to** something like listening to a boring lecture, or playing soccer.

**Side topic:**

Your combination of *to acquiesc in sth.* plus *playing soccer* has an (unwanted or wanted) comical effect. Basically you are saying

> I acquiesc in running hectically around and chasing a ball

which contrasts the idea of you moving quickly and forcefully whith your supposed quiecy, as the verb *to acquiesc* of course is rooted in the Latin verb *quiēscō* (“repose, lie still”). So, *acquiesc in running* is a bit contradictive.

Comment: Understood, thanks! Love the explanation of the transitive and intransitive verbs as well

Comment: The comical effect is intentional, it's supposed to be a bit eye catching - meant as an opening for a grad school statement of purpose